# Cannot use '--build-native-deps' along with '--build' flag

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm getting the above error from an Azure DevOps pipeline while deploying python code to Azure functions. The pipeline was previously running without errors (last run 12 days ago). The task code is as follows;

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs)-prod $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools
func azure functionapp publish <app-name> --python --build-native-deps
```

The last line is throwing the error, but there is no "--build" flag specified, which is is confusing me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of azure-functions-core-tools are you using? I faced the same issue with versions 2.7.1724 and 3.0.1740. Downgrading the azure-functions-core-tools package to version 2.7.1704 fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, there seems to be a behavior change between versions of the core tools. The script above is run on an Ubuntu package/deploy agent on every deployment through Azure DevOps Pipelines, which is triggered by a commit on GitHub. The latest version where I can see the pipeline was _successful_ was **2.7.1585-1**. It _failed_ on version **2.7.1724-1**.

Answer (score 1):

So seems there is a behavior change on the function core tools after version 2.7.1585-1. The deployment works by removing the "--build-native-deps" flag.

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works.